# Rubber plant is dying!

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, ficus

I can't seem to save my rubber plant for some reason! Would really appreciate all the help I can get please :)

I bought a rubber plant last year and it has been okay ever since I moved it from the hallway (little light) to the living room (brighter). I've been having a constant problem with yellow leaves which is apparently due to over watering so I left it for 2-weeks but the yellow leaves were still coming! I also experience brown/dried leaves (they are still there now!) I am not sure with the reason why this is happening. The main thing I am concerned with is one of the stems.

This single stem has lost all its leaves and the stalk started off floppy and was drooping a few months ago. I read online it was because of over watering but the other 2 stems were absolutely fine! I tried not watering it for 2-3weeks and no improvement. It just appeared to be this problematic stem :( I am unsure what happened since right now, the other two stems seem okay but this single stem is dying.

Please may someone shed light onto this problem!

Comment: Can you add a picture?

Comment: Thank you for your question; if could include an overall illustration, close illustrations of the tops, close illustrations of top sides & undersides of healthy & of yellowing leaves,  overall height(s), soil, current amount & frequency of watering & nutrient, and daytime & night time temperatures, could be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Also, you can include illustrations that appear within the text of your questions by clicking on the scenery/mountain silhouette button, and then adding the images according to the instructions which appear; and you can adjust text of your questions and answers, by clicking on the 'edit' button in the lower left corner of your question screen & answer screen. Thank you, and Welcome to the site!